# Easy Python Syntax Error: pipe character (|)

Tags: python

I am new to python and jupyter notebook. When creating a table, a syntax error keeps popping up, it seems that python cannot recognize the pipe character (|). Can anyone help me? Many thanks!

```
| This | is   |
|------|------|
|   a  | table|
```

I am using a MAC and there is a pipe character on the keyboard. 
[image: Screenshot for problem]

Comment: I hate to say it : it all depends on context. You should show us your code.

Comment: You should probably read [the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) or some other introductory material.  The pipe character `|` has meaning in python, but it's not for building tables (python doesn't really have a concept of a table).

Comment: Thanks so much @PatrickHaugh. I''ll have a look at the documents.

Answer (score 0):

Actually python doesn´t store data in tables. But you can store data you need in e.g. list and then use module texttable to output a table.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, python doesn’t really have a concept of a table. Also the pipe character | has meaning in python, but it's not for building tables. The pipe character is a bitwise or of characters. For example, 00001111 | 10000000 = 10001111 in binary.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write anything directly
you can write

```
a=|this|is   |
b=------------
c=|a   |table|

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```